# Unkown number of objects.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

If the number of permutations of $n$ different things taken $4$ at a time in which one particular thing does not occur is equal to that in which it does occur, find $n$.

My teacher says $n=8$. I don't understand how can that be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ be the set of $n$ objects, and let $a$ be the particular object. There are $n-1$ objects in $S\setminus\{a\}$, so there are $\binom{n-1}4$ ways to choose a set of $4$ objects **not** containing $a$. Each of these sets can be permuted in $4!$ ways, so there are $4!\binom{n-1}4$ ways to choose a permutation of $4$ objects **not** containing $a$.

To choose a set of $4$ objects **containing** $a$, we must choose $a$ together with $3$ of the remaining $n-1$ objects of $S$, and we can do that in $\binom{n-1}3$ ways. Once again there are $4!$ ways to permute the $4$ objects, so there are $4!\binom{n-1}3$ ways to choose a permutation of $4$ objects **containing** $a$.

The hypothesis is therefore that

$$4!\binom{n-1}4=4!\binom{n-1}3\;,$$

which we can simplify to

$$\binom{n-1}4=\binom{n-1}3\;.$$

It’s a general fact that if $0\le k,\ell\le m$, then $\dbinom{m}k=\dbinom{m}\ell$ if and only if $\ell=m-k$, or $k+\ell=m$: thus, we must have $4+3=n-1$, and hence $n=8$.

If you like, you can then do the arithmetic to check:

$$\binom74=\frac{7!}{4!3!}=35=\frac{7!}{3!4!}=\binom73\;.$$

**Added:** Alternatively, you can argue that there are $(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)$ ways to choose a permutation of $4$ objects **not** including $a$. To pick a permutation of $4$ objects **including** $a$, you can first pick the other $3$ in $(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)$ ways, but then you have $4$ choices for where in to put $a$ in the permutation, so you can accomplish the task in $4(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)$ ways altogether. Thus,

$$(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)=4(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)\;,$$

so $n=4=4$, and $n=8$.

Comment: But what you did is use combination.  The question says permutation.

Comment: @Hollow: The number of permutations is just $4!$ times the number of combinations, so you get the same result. However, I should have made that explicit; I’ve revised the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: What I did was: When we have include that particular object we have (n-1)P3 ways to the rest three and when we do not include we have (n-1)P4. Whats wrong here?

Comment: @Hollow: You’re missing a factor of $4$ in the first one: there are $(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)$ ways to choose and order the other $3$ objects, and then there are $4$ places in which you could insert the object $a$, for a total of $4(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)$ permutations. Thus, $$4(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)=(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)\;,$$ so $4=n-4$, and $n=8$.